# RDLC Moves Up Visibility Hidden

Tags: visibility, rdlc, hidden

Hi I create a RDLC windows report , I put one logo Image top of page, and I put one textbox center of page.

And I set Visibility of Hidden Of Logo Image that 
=iif(Parameters!TXTGOSTER.Value="Show",false,true)

When I set TXTGOSTER parameters with "Hide" the logo image hidden its ok but the TEXTBOX MOVES UP , not center of page.

How can I fix position of text box that does not move up when the image hidden.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve white space when hiding textbox in rdlc file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825415/preserve-white-space-when-hiding-textbox-in-rdlc-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can add one table with 2 rows and 1 column: the first row contains the image, the second row, bigger, has the title text in the center.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That might cause other undesirable structure changes.  A cleaner solution in my opinion is to pair the potentially hidden element with a placeholder element which is visible, thereby causing the layout to be preserved, when the subject element is hidden. (see duplicate question linked above)